# php client detect file updates on server

Tags: php, json, apache, xampp

I have a server:

ubuntu, running Xampp.

multiple clients:

Raspberry pi, running Apache

all connected via LAN network

I have a PHP code on the server that does the following:

- gets information from the database
- write it in json files
- Accepts REST API request and sends response

on the client side, a php code that does:

- send REST API calls

  - gets the response and write it to a text file

The database might be updated anytime, and the json files will be updated accordingly.

I want the clients to execute the code whenever the json files are updated.
Is there any way to make the clients monitor these files?
or make the server send a signal to all clients when the files are updated?

Comment: Yes one of my senior has developed such system called jAPi: https://www.phpclasses.org/package/8267-PHP-Handle-client-and-server-API-calls.html Look here how to use it

Comment: Why not keep sending the API calls and let the client check if they are updated or not?